# C++ k shortest paths algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Does someone know if there is any production-ready `K-shortest-paths` algorithm for `C++`?

The only available implementation ([k-shortest-paths](http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-paths/)), unfortunately, leaks memory, has counter-intuitive interfaces and another *"reinvented wheel"* - the `Graph` class.

I'm looking for something better, probably, `boost::graph`-based.

*There are two possible algorithms available - `simple Yen's algorithm` and `optimized Yen's algorithm`, both would suit me.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another one, but you'll have to check if this also leaks memory.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksp/files/ksp/ksp-1.0/